# How do I get the heading elements from the TableForm option TableHeadings?

Tags: options, list-manipulation

The following,

```
table = 
  TableForm[ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}], 
   TableAlignments -> Right, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"One", "Two", "Three"}}]
```

generates a table with headings:

[image]

I see that its `FullForm` is

```
TableForm[
  List[
    List[HoldForm[\[Placeholder]], HoldForm[\[Placeholder]], HoldForm[\[Placeholder]]],
    List[HoldForm[\[Placeholder]], HoldForm[\[Placeholder]], HoldForm[\[Placeholder]]],
    List[HoldForm[\[Placeholder]], HoldForm[\[Placeholder]], HoldForm[\[Placeholder]]]],
    Rule[TableAlignments, Right],
    Rule[TableHeadings, List[None, List["One", "Two", "Three"]]
  ]
]
```

and I could parse this to retrieve the value of `TableHeadings`.

But is there a more canonical approach?

I found that for plots, one can use `Options[plot]`, but I couldn't find a counterpart for tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Options` seems to work just fine:

```
Options[table, TableHeadings]
```

> (* {TableHeadings -> {None, {"One", "Two", "Three"}}} *)

... slightly generalized:

```
getopt[obj_, opt_] := opt /. Options[obj, opt]

getopt[table, TableHeadings]
```

> (* {None, {"One", "Two", "Three"}} *)

Comment: D'oh! I tried that but my test case was flawed—the options were stripped while copy-pasting a table in TableForm for use in InputForm. Thank you.

Comment: Hehe - happy to help :D

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[InputForm[yourTableFormRefHere], HoldPattern[TableHeadings -> a_] :> a, Infinity]
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Works, thanks! I realized though that `Options` does work and I was simply misusing it.

Comment: @acheong87 - lol, I assumed based on the quality of your questions that it didn't, so didn't bother to check. We both get 1 DOH! point...

Comment: IMO, a completely reasonable assumption given the context, haha.